# Authorization based on custom Header (Apache)

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy, http-headers, authorization

I have a service running behind a Apache Reverse-Proxy that uses the custom headers "username" and "role" to identify users and their role.

I want Apache HTTPD to restrict access to to people whose custom HTTP-header "groupmembership" contains one of the following: "viewer","publisher","administrator".

The Apache sits behind another proxy which authenticates users and populates the HTTP Headers "username" and "groupmembership" where the contents of "groupmembership" is a comma-separated list with groups.

For reference I have included a draft of the architecture.
[http-proxy-auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhevJ.png)

How would this be possible? I have tried using a require directive like `Require expr %{HTTP:iv_groupmembership} in { 'viewer', 'publisher', 'administrator' }` inside `<Location />` to no avail.

Could this instead work with mod_rewrite?

Here is the reverse-proxy config using mod_proxy and mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
<Proxy *>
  Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyRequests Off

# store variable values with dummy rewrite rules
RewriteRule . - [E=req_scheme:%{REQUEST_SCHEME}]
RewriteRule . - [E=http_host:%{HTTP_HOST}]
RewriteRule . - [E=req_uri:%{REQUEST_URI}]

# set header with variables
RequestHeader set X-RSC-Request "%{req_scheme}e://%{http_host}e%{req_uri}e"

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket
RewriteRule /(.*) ws://localhost:3939/$1 [P,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket
RewriteRule /(.*) http://localhost:3939/$1 [P,L]
ProxyPass / http://172.17.0.1:3939/  
ProxyPassReverse / http://172.17.0.1:3939/
```

Thanks for any hints.

Edit: Basically, the question boils down to: How can I check if the comma-separated list in the `groupmembership` Header contains either 'Administrator', 'Publisher' or 'Viewer'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. If you have a comma-separated list in header `groupmembership`, then use the first regex expression. One value in the list has to match to grant access.

If you want to match an exact value in `iv_groupmembership`, then uncomment the <strike>second</strike> third expression (and comment the first).

**Edit:**

- added `RequestHeader set role` example, uncomment as needed. I only tested this with `Header set role` (in the response, no backend), but should work with `RequestHeader` the same way.

**Edit2:**

- removed `<Location/>` for clarity
- added example for `X-Auth-Token` check combined with `groupmembership`

**Sample config:**

```
    # test for string in comma-separated values, one of the values must match
    <If "%{HTTP:groupmembership} !~ /(^|,)(viewer|publisher|administrator)(,|$)/">

    # combined: X-Auth-Token must be set or one of the roles must exist
#   <If "%{HTTP:X-Auth-Token} == '' && %{HTTP:groupmembership} !~ /(^|,)(viewer|publisher|administrator)(,|$)/">

    # alternative: test for a single value in "iv_groupmembership" (exact match)
#   <If "! %{HTTP:iv_groupmembership} in { 'viewer', 'publisher', 'administrator' }">

        Require all denied
    </If>

    # set role of groupmembership
#   <If "%{HTTP:groupmembership} =~ /(^|,)viewer(,|$)/">
#       RequestHeader set role viewer
#   </If>
#   <ElseIf "%{HTTP:groupmembership} =~ /(^|,)publisher(,|$)/">
#       RequestHeader set role publisher
#   </ElseIf>
#   <ElseIf "%{HTTP:groupmembership} =~ /(^|,)administrator(,|$)/">
#       RequestHeader set role administrator
#   </ElseIf>

    # set role of iv_groupmembership
#   RequestHeader set role "expr=%{HTTP:iv_groupmembership}"
```

Modifying the headers in Apache (like `RequestHeader set iv_groupmembership "viewer"`) to debug/test the config doesn't work, 
you need to set the header very early.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#vars

> The expression parser provides a number of variables of the form %{HTTP_HOST}. Note that the value of a variable may depend on the phase of the request processing in which it is evaluated. For example, an expression used in an <If > directive is evaluated before authentication is done. Therefore, %{REMOTE_USER} will not be set in this case.

You can test the configuration with wget from commandline, replace `localhost` with your hostname.

```
# HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
wget -S -O - http://localhost
wget -S -O - --header='groupmembership: xviewer' http://localhost
wget -S -O - --header='groupmembership: administratorx' http://localhost
wget -S -O - --header='iv_groupmembership: xviewer' http://localhost

# HTTP/1.1 200 OK
wget -S -O - --header='groupmembership: foo,viewer' http://localhost
wget -S -O - --header='groupmembership: publisher,foo' http://localhost
wget -S -O - --header='iv_groupmembership: viewer' http://localhost
wget -S -O - --header='iv_groupmembership: publisher' http://localhost
wget -S -O - --header='iv_groupmembership: administrator' http://localhost
```

Tested with Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)

Comment: Thanks for the really helpful answer!

Comment: Now, I actually need both: authorized access and setting a header "role" based on an exact match.

Comment: There is one problem. The RewriteRule [P,L] lines will take precedence on the Location blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Freddy, 
I got it working with the `Require` and Expressions directives for the authorization part and putting the `RequestHeader` directive inside `<Virtualhost>` for setting the Role-Headers.

The final config looks like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName ...
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html

  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
  SSLCipherSuite HIGH:3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!SEED:!IDEA

  SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/...
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/...

  RewriteEngine on
  #ProxyPreserveHost on

  <Proxy *>
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>
  ProxyRequests Off

  # store variable values with dummy rewrite rules
  RewriteRule . - [E=req_scheme:%{REQUEST_SCHEME}]
  RewriteRule . - [E=http_host:%{HTTP_HOST}]
  RewriteRule . - [E=req_uri:%{REQUEST_URI}]

  # set header with variables
  RequestHeader set X-RSC-Request "%{req_scheme}e://%{http_host}e%{req_uri}e"

  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket
  RewriteRule /(.*) ws://localhost:3939/$1 [P,L]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket
  RewriteRule /(.*) http://localhost:3939/$1 [P,L]

  # test for string in comma-separated values, one of the values must match
  <If "%{HTTP:iv_groupmembership} !~ /(^|,)(Viewer|Publisher|Administrator)(,|$)/ && -z %{HTTP:X-Auth-Token} && %{HTTP:Authorization} !~ /Key .+/">
    Require all denied
  </If>

  # set role of groupmembership
  <If "%{HTTP:iv_groupmembership} =~ /(^|,)Viewer(,|$)/">
     RequestHeader set Role viewer
  </If>
  <ElseIf "%{HTTP:iv_groupmembership} =~ /(^|,)Publisher(,|$)/">
     RequestHeader set Role publisher
  </ElseIf>
  <ElseIf "%{HTTP:iv_groupmembership} =~ /(^|,)Administrator(,|$)/">
    RequestHeader set Role administrator
  </ElseIf>
</Virtualhost>
```

Thanks a lot!

**Edit:** how can I add additional logic in the `Require` directive, so that if the header `X-Auth-Token` is present, access is granted anyway?

**Edit2:** Thanks again @Freddy for the pointer to Apache expression-logic, I adapted the test for existence of the "X-Auth-Token" Header with `-z %{HTTP:X-Auth-Token}` and could add another condition to pass through requests containing a key inside the "authorization" header.

Comment: See my **Edit2**, I also changed the syntax of the negated regex expr from `! %{..} =~` to `%{..} !~`, just so you know when you adapt the example.

Comment: Thanks @Freddy, it's working as expected, now =)